# TraceFs: ioctl: inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Hi I am getting this error: ioctl: inappropriate ioctl for device
on the ioctl() call shown below.

```
fd = open(mount, O_RDONLY);

destid = ioctl(fd, TRACEFS_IOCTL_ADD_OUTPUT_DRIVERS, data);



#define IOCBASE 10

#define TRACEFS_IOCTL_ADD_OUTPUT_DRIVERS    _IOW(0x15, IOCBASE + 0, int)
```

I am not sure how to debug this issue or go about resolving the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That ioctl is only available with TraceFS (a specific filesystem). I assume you need to mount the filesystem as TraceFS to fix the problem.

Comment: The tracefs module is already loaded and the file system is already mounted.

Comment: @user1253073 It would probably help to give us the line from `mount` that you are trying to run this ioctl on then.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by: the line from mount. I am pasting below the entry from the mount command, then I am pasting the mount command I use to mount tracefs. The line that is causing this error is: `destid = ioctl(fd, TRACEFS_IOCTL_ADD_OUTPUT_DRIVERS, data);
`

Comment: none on /dev/tracefs-upper type tracefs (rw,dir=/dev/lower,debug=1)

Comment: mount -t tracefs -o dir=${LOWERDIR},debug=${4:-$DEBUG} none  ${MOUNTPOINT} || exit $?

Comment: Why are you mounting a directory in /dev. That looks suspicious.

Comment: :D, I guess its why I am here, so shall I just create a mnt folder at root and mount there instead?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest creating a folder somewhere not in one of the special filesystems (/dev, /sys, /proc). They're example suggests /mnt/tracefs as the destination point, and using /mnt wouldn't be a bad idea.